# How do I uninstall the Sentinel Drivers from Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, windows-update

I have tried several times to uninstall the sentinel drivers from my Windows 8 machine. It is a Toshiba laptop 64 bit system. Let me know step by step how do I do it, because I have tried other methods like the command prompt uninstall and nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

Try.

1. Open the link:  [sentinelcustomer.safenet-inc.com](http://sentinelcustomer.safenet-inc.com/sentineldownloads/).
2. Click on: `Sentinel HASP/LDK - Command Line Run-time Installer`.
3. It will download a compressed folder named: `Sentinel_LDK_Run-time_cmd_line`.
4. Unzip this folder and copy its address.
5. Open the command prompt by typing `cmd` from the run window(press [image] + <kbd>R</kbd>).
6. In the command prompt window, type `cd`, and paste the copied address and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
7. After that, while still in the command prompt, type `haspdinst -remove` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.